# collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status windows 7 SE

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, codeblocks

I installed CMake, OpenCV following [this forum](https://medium.com/@sourabhjigjinni/install-opencv-4-0-0-for-c-windows-7-10-code-blocks-tdm-gcc-64-dff65addf162) on my Windows 7 laptop. 
When I tried to build main code, I got this bug: `collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

This is my code :

```
/**
  @file videocapture_basic.cpp
  @brief A very basic sample for using VideoCapture and VideoWriter
  @author PkLab.net
  @date Aug 24, 2016
*/

#include <opencv2/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat frame;
    //--- INITIALIZE VIDEOCAPTURE
    VideoCapture cap;
    // open the default camera using default API
    // cap.open(0);
    // OR advance usage: select any API backend
    int deviceID = 0;             // 0 = open default camera
    int apiID = cv::CAP_ANY;      // 0 = autodetect default API
    // open selected camera using selected API
    cap.open(deviceID, apiID);
    // check if we succeeded
    if (!cap.isOpened()) {
        cerr << "ERROR! Unable to open camera\n";
        return -1;
    }

    //--- GRAB AND WRITE LOOP
    cout << "Start grabbing" << endl
        << "Press any key to terminate" << endl;
    for (;;)
    {
        // wait for a new frame from camera and store it into 'frame'
        cap.read(frame);
        // check if we succeeded
        if (frame.empty()) {
            cerr << "ERROR! blank frame grabbed\n";
            break;
        }
        // show live and wait for a key with timeout long enough to show images
        imshow("Live", frame);
        if (waitKey(5) >= 0)
            break;
    }
    // the camera will be deinitialized automatically in VideoCapture destructor
    return 0;
}
```

This is the error in the build log:

```
C:\opencv_install\install\x64\mingw\lib\OpenCVConfig.cmake: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s))
```

This is the error in build message:
[build message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epAiV.jpg)

I looked many forums but didn't find a response of my bug. Please could you help me?

Comment: The error message says OpenCVConfig.cmake is not formatted correctly. Can you open this file in a text editor and re-save it? Maybe somehow it was corrupted?

Comment: Answer to #Squareskittles : I tried but it isn't worked. I got a same bug.